# Make Indicator Only Visible For 1 Security

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have an indicator that is unique to a security.  I only want it visible when that security is selected.  Is there a way to make it visible only for that security?  Its an annoyance to have to turn it off every time.

Comment: Can be done if you have the code of that indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a boolean condition to check the symbol, which you can then use as a condition for plotting, or with other renders such as lines, boxes, etc you can wrap the code in an if statement which only executes if it is the correct symbol.

```
sym = input.string("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", title = "symbol for visible")

visible = syminfo.tickerid == sym

plot(visible ? close : na)



var line hh_line = na

hh = ta.highest(high, 50)

new_hh = ta.change(hh) != 0

if visible
    if na(hh_line)
        hh_line := line.new(x1 = bar_index, y1 = hh, x2 = bar_index + 1, y2 = hh, extend = extend.both)
    else
        if new_hh
            line.set_xy1(hh_line, x = bar_index, y = hh)
            line.set_xy2(hh_line, x = bar_index + 1, y = hh)
        else
            line.set_x2(hh_line, x = bar_index + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I can make it work, but its not ideal.  Basically I have to take every variable that is plotted and AND it with visible.  I'd really like to be able to use the visible variable to jump to the end so the lengthy code is not calculated when I click on a new symbol.  I can not seem to make this work.

sym = input.string("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", title = "symbol for visible")  
visible = syminfo.tickerid == sym  
  
if (visible)  
    ##code  
    plot(indicator)  
else  
    do nothing

Comment: Now that i think of it, you might be able to do something else by modifying the source(s) for calculations instead. Say `src = visible ? close : na`. You might be able to cut it short that way. So for example, `ta.sma(src, length)` if `visible` is false, nothing will be plotted due to the na value.